# Is there a name of such functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $U$ be an open subset of $ \mathbb R^n$ and consider  $f :\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ with the properties that  $ f( \partial U)=0$ and $f$ takes negative values on $U$. My questions:

1. Is there any name for such functions in Mathematics Literature?
2. Given any set $U$ as above can we always find a **continuous** function with above properties?
3. Are these functions important at all?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would call it a negative bump function. You should look at the wikipedia article on it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: 3. As per the wiki article - they are heavily used in analysis.

Comment: Why is it so clear that there needn't be a smooth function with these properties? I can only see that even being plausible if the boundary is quite irregular.

Comment: Also, as for a continuous example, try $f(x)=-d(x,\partial U)$. It should also be smooth away from the boundary (but it is not smooth up to the boundary).

Comment: @Ian yeah you are right,i thought something stupid.

Answer (score 4):

There's an old theorem (due to Whitney, I think) that says the following:

> Given any smooth manifold $M$ and any closed subset $K\subseteq M$, there exists a smooth function $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ that satisfies $f=0$ on $K$ and $f>0$ on $M\smallsetminus K$.

You can find a proof in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (2nd ed.), Theorem 2.29.

In your situation, if you apply this with $K=\mathbb R^n\smallsetminus U$ and then take the negative of the resulting function, you get a smooth solution to question 2.

Is there a name for such functions? They might sometimes be called (negative) bump functions, but that term more commonly is applied to a function whose zero set *contains* a given closed set (or equivalently, whose support is contained in some given open set). In the special case that $\partial U$ is a smooth hypersurface, a smooth function $f$ such that $f<0$ (or $>0$) on $U$, $f^{-1}(0) = \partial U$, and $df\ne 0$ on $\partial U$ is called a ***defining function*** for $U$.

As to your third question, bump functions and defining functions are extremely useful throughout differential geometry and PDE theory. But functions of the type guaranteed by the Whitney theorem I quoted above seem to be mainly curiosities. They provide an answer to the question "How special are the zero sets of smooth functions?" (Answer: not special at all, except for the fact that they're closed.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Sorry Sir,Do you mean $f^{-1}(0) = \partial U$ instead of $f^{-1}(U) = \partial U$?

Comment: Oops, you're right. I fixed it.